# How to get value from input field with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-extraction

How can I get the value of an specific input field with Javascript?

Lets take this shopify shop for example: https://geekymate.com/products/magic-doormat-1?variant=18941211607138

I am trying to create a script which is automatically applying an discount code based on the quantity filled in the quantity field.

But to do that I need to be able to get the latest value of the field. 
How would the code look like to get the latest/current value?

EDIT: Thank you for the hint with the question. I do know that I need to use getElementById ( For the linked page above it would be this: var x = document.getElementById("Quanity").value; ) but how do I always get the latest input automatically if the enduser is changing the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the question. I do know that I need to use getElementById but how do I always get the latest input automatically if the enduser is changing the value?

Comment: Have you thought about an event listener for keyup?

Comment: @Elliot Thank you for your comment. Do you mind explaining a little bit more? 
I am still a beginner with javascript and I am not really familiar with it yet. Just started to learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are also correct (using jQuery `.keyup`), but you can also use this solution below (which is better). This solution uses pure javascript.

The code selects the element by using [`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and uses [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to do something when input changes.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
window.onload = function() {
  text.addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log(text.value);
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="text" />
```

Or you can use the following if you want a jQuery solution. This uses jQuery [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

```js
$("#text").bind("input", function() {
  console.log($("#text").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" />
```

Comment: I did not know it was this easy to achieve! 
It really shows that I am still at a very beginner stage of learning javascript and jquery. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanations and the code snippets to test them!

Comment: I just ran into this error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. 
As far as I understand that error could be caused because the script is already executed before the DOM finished loading. Is that correct ? If yes how to be sure it is executed after the DOM finished loading ?

Comment: @Salexes it either means that the element you're trying to add an event listener on doesn't exist, or yes. The DOM hasn't loaded. I updated my solution. In this case, you should put `window.onload` before just like I did in the updated answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189493/discussion-between-salexes-and-aniket-g).

Answer (score 2):

`keyup()` function ;)

It runs each time, when user types new text. 
Also, you can use `input()` or `change()` functions.

In jQuery it works like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#InputID', function(){
    //...code...
    var discount = Number( document.getElementById('InputID').value )*10/100;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a Jquery function that runs on keypress. I've included a snippet below to see how it would tie in with an input field.

```js
$('#code').keyup(function() {
    var discountcode = this.value;
    console.log(discountcode);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="code" type="test" />
```

Keyup runs every time a specific element is lifted. Imagine someone enters 'Hello'

You will see the following logged:

'H' 'He' 'Hel' 'Hell' 'Hello'

Comment: @AniketG I was elaborating on my comment and was still writing it up before I saw the answer below. Since it has a code snippet and was posted 2 minutes between each other, I don't think it's a big deal.

Comment: you can keep it if you want. I just know the one thing I hate is seeing multiple answers (that are the same). As I have on every other occasion, I'm upvoting the one that went up first. Which was the other one

Answer (score 1):

look at the code snippet. using JavaScript to get the values. and can use `addEventListener` to detect the change and use `detectChange` function to get the latest values.

```js
var discount = [];

function detectChange() {
  var table = document.getElementsByClassName("shappify_qb_grid")[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      if (j == 1) {
        row = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
        rate = parseFloat(row);
        if (rate && discount.indexOf(rate) < 0) {
          discount.push(parseFloat(row));
          console.log('---', parseFloat(row));
        }
      }
      // console.log('discount : ', discount);
    }
  }
}

detectChange();
console.log('discount : ', discount);
```

```html
<table class="shappify_qb_grid" border=1>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Discount</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Buy 1</td>
  <td>0% Off</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Buy 2</td>
  <td>10% Off</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Buy 4</td>
  <td>12% Off</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Buy 5</td>
  <td>14% Off</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Buy 6</td>
  <td>17% Off</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the code you posted correctly. If I would change the quantity input field to e.g. 4 it would automatically assoiate it with 12% discount?

Still a javascript beginner so I just want to be sure to understand each step of the code

Answer (score 1):

This work for me!

```
document.getElementById("text").value;

<input id="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `document.getElementById();` -command to get the existence of the referenced element in your HTML page. Then use the same technique of assigning attributes in the original HTML coding rules.

Use `document.getElementById('able').value = 'whatever';`.

Comment: The question is about getting the value, not changing the value. There are also answers from over a year ago that explain how to do this.